# Get file full path in java

Tags: java

When I pass `File file` to a method I'm trying to get its full path like `file.getAbsolutePath();` I always get the same result no matter which one I use either absolute or canonical path `PATH_TO_MY_WORKSPACE/projectName/filename` and it is not there, how can I get exact location of the file?

Thank you

**DETAILS:**

Here is some code and this solutions(its bad but its working):

```
 private static void doSomethingToDirectory(File factDir) throws IOException {
            File[] dirContents = factDir.listFiles();

            if(factDir.isDirectory() && dirContents.length > 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < dirContents.length; i++) {
                    for (String str : dirContents[i].list()) {
                        if(str.equals(TEMP_COMPARE_FILE)){
                            process(new File(dirContents[i].getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + str));
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
```

I'm looping trough directories where factDir is `src/main`, I'm seeking toBeProcessed.txt files only that is TEMP_COMPARE_FILE value and I'm sending them to process method which reads the file and does processing of it.

If someone could better solution I'd be greatful

Comment: are you sure it isn't there? have you refresh the file tree? (if using eclipse ;))

Comment: How did you create that file object?

Comment: @Sebi sure I did, @Peter yes I did :)

Comment: ??? AFAIK "yes" is not an appropriate answer to my question :-/

Comment: @Péter Török sorry didn't read it properly like methodName(new File("filename"))

Comment: It sounds like to me you are just instantiating a File object, but that doesn't actually create anything on disk until you write to the file using a Writer or an Outputstream, or call `createNewFile()`

Comment: No I'm not trying to create a new file I'm trying to pass a file to the method which does processing on the file, but when I try to access it from method appears that file doesn't exist but it does

Comment: I misunderstood then.  If you could provide us with some code that would go a long ways towards trying to figure out what is happening.

Comment: some source code will help answering yr problem !

Comment: alright guys here it is some source code thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This quote from the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) might be helpful:

> A pathname, whether abstract or in string form, may be either *absolute* or *relative*. An absolute pathname is complete in that no other information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes. A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the `java.io` package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property `user.dir`, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

I interpret this so that if you create your `File` object with `new File("filename")` where `filename` is a relative path, that path will not be converted into an absolute path even by a call to `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

**Update:** now that you posted code, I can think of some ways to improve it:

- you could use a [FilenameFilter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) to find the desired files,
- note that `list` and `listFiles` return `null` for non-directory objects, so we need an extra check for that,
- you could also use `listFiles()` again in the inner loop, thus avoiding the need to create new `File` objects with hand-assembled paths. (Btw note that appending `\\` manually to the path is not portable; the proper way would be to use `File.separator`).

The end result is

```
private static void doSomethingToDirectory(File factDir) throws IOException {
  if (factDir.isDirectory()) {
    for (File file : factDir.listFiles()) {
      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : file.listFiles(new MyFilter())) {
          process(child);
        }
      }
    }           
  }
}

class MyFilter implements FilenameFilter {
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.equals(TEMP_COMPARE_FILE);
  }
}
```

Note that this code mimics the behaviour of your original piece of code as much as I understood it; most notably, it finds the files with the proper name only in the *direct subdirectories* of `factDir`, nonrecursively.

Comment: w0w Peter I must definitely say this, I think this is one of the best answers I've ever gotten on SO, you MyFilter class suggestion reduced like so much code, just AMAZING. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a way it may help you if and only if the file is in the program directory.

first you get the program directory by :

```
new File(".").getCanonicalPath()
```

then :

if `file` is inside a specific directory like `folder\\filename`
the full path will be

```
(new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\folder\\filename")
```

or if `file` is directly inside the program directory:
the full path will be

```
(new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\filename")
```

i wish this answer help you :)