# How to show the file name only in JList?

Tags: java, swing, file, jlist

Following code prints the whole directory path:

```
JList list = new JList(new File(path).listFiles());
```

I only need the file name, not the path. How do I change the code to do this?

I tried this:

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\images\\jpgs";
JList list = new JList((new File(path.toString()).listFiles()).getName());
```

but i get an error. would anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Use a `ListCellRenderer` and render it as needed. E.G. as seen in [How to create JList with icon and text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336802/how-to-create-jlist-with-icon-and-text)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get file full path in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981972/get-file-full-path-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> try {
>               File[] fileList = (new File("D:\Software")).listFiles();

```
        String[] fileName = new String[fileList.length];

        for(int i=0; i<fileList.length;i++)
        {
            fileName[i] = fileList[i].getName();
        }
        JList<String> jList = new JList<String>(fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
new File(absolutePath).getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here (**[Duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981972/get-file-full-path-in-java)**) you have to use `absolutePath`.